# Useful PHP database class

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a small PHP website. I need a MySql database access class that is easy to configure and work with.

Does not need to be a full framework, I only need a max. few classes.

Comment: From Zend Framework you can really just take what you want. Even only Zend_Db! And there is of course a mysql pdo adapter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ADODb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) is pretty easy to work with and worth considering. Some illustrative samples:

```
  //connect
  $dsn = 'mysql://user:pwd@localhost/mydb'; 
  $db = ADONewConnection($dsn);  

  //get a single value     
  $value=$db->GetOne("select foo from bar where x=?", array($x));

  //get a row
  $row=$db->GetRow("select * from bar where x=?", array($x));

  //easy insert example
  $record=array("id"=>1, "foo"=>"bar");
  $db->AutoExecute("table", $record, "INSERT");
```

Comment: I found ADODb to be the easiest one to set up.

Comment: Hi Mr. Dixon,
But this library needs some good documentation. Do you know of any web resource where I can find some help with it. I tried to create a class for database related tasks using this library but couldn't do it well.

Comment: I found the documentation was OK (see http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm )

Answer (score 14):

PDO works great for me, even tho it's not a fully blown library like PEAR::MDB2.

PDO is a compiled extension of PHP5, so there's a small performance benefit as well.

Comment: In my next project I will also consider this library.

Answer (score 5):

If you're happy with it being MySql specific, [MySqli](http://php.net/mysqli) is the default choice.

Answer (score 4):

I think [PEAR::MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have really specific needs, I would recommend you take a look at [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo), which is bundled with PHP >= 5.1.

It's fully object-oriented, facilitates compatibility between DB engines ; and it's integration in PHP as a C extension makes it probably a bit faster than equivalents developped in PHP.

You could also take a look at the [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) extension, which provides both a function-oriented and an object-oriented interface.

But I'd rather go to PDO, I think...

And, now that you are spending (investing ;-) ) some time looking for new stuff, you could take a look at prepared statements : they are supported by both [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), and are nice for (amongst other things) security reasons (no need to worry about escaping your data to prevent SQL injections)

If you had said you need a full ORM solution, I would have pointed you to [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), which is really a great ORM framework ; but it's probably way too much for your needs...

Comment: PDO does not facilitate compatibility between RDBMSes. It lacks constructs to hide the differences between things like how datetimes are handled differently across all RDBMSes. PDO is still a good choice for accessing any one RDBMS. But it is incomplete if cross-RDBMS support is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html) from [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/). Later you may include mode components from ZF.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [this](http://www.micahcarrick.com/04-19-2005/php-mysql-database-class.html) once in a while, It's pretty good! (And has an awesome autoslash feature), it's easily customizable and pretty small, but it had everything I needed. You can probably relatively easy expand it to support caching or whatever you desire.

Good luck finding whatever suits you best. :)

Answer (score 1):

Also digg's PDB, which is a simple PDO wrapper or something can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/digg/wiki/PDB

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and lightweight db class is

http://code.google.com/p/edb-php-class/

```
 <?php
    $result = $db->q("select * from `users`limit 3");

    foreach($result as $a){
            $a = (object) $a;
            echo $a->id.' '.$a->name.' '.$a->url.' '.$a->img.'</br>';
    }


    $result = $db->line("select * from `users` where id = '300' limit 1");
    echo $result['name']; 
    echo $result['surname']; 



    $name = $db->one("select name from `ilike_pics` where id = '300' limit 1");
    echo $name;
    ?>
```

Comment: Uh wow, I will test this and hope it works. It looks really nice.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for PHP's PDO (PHP Data Objects) extension. I use it alongside a really handy database class that extends PDO. You can find this open-source project on Google's Project Hosting at http://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class), which utilizes MySQLi and prepared statements (this means that you will be protected from SQL injection). Class is well documented.