# Using the Codeigniter DB_forge Class as a standalone

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'd like to use the following class from codeigniter:
[DB_forge.php](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/src/fa2ee6e30941/system/database/DB_forge.php)
(or any other class that can create and edit tables)

Now, I know just including the class in my procedural php script won't work, as this class uses CI's database class. Can someone walk me through what I have to do in order to be able to use this class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this, but it looks like someone crafted a standalone version of CI's ActiveRecord + DBforge based on the 1.7.1 version:

http://www.documentopia.com/downloads/

I don't necessarily endorse this, but it might be worth a shot - I could not find anything else, and I thought I saw this question here before but I cannot find that either.

Depending on your needs, you may be able to just use a stripped down CI installation.

There are a lot of suggestions here that may help as well:

[Useful PHP database class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218714/useful-php-database-class)

Comment: oops, didn't mean to send the comment yet. well, i hope you can help me a bit further. can you give me a hint what i have to do in order to use the class. do i need to create a DB Object and then pass that object to the db forge class? Time's running out and i'd love to use this class.

Comment: Like I said, I haven't used it (the one I linked to). You could try running a CI installation within your app, and creating a controller that handles all the DB Forge stuff, if time is an issue as you say. That would save you loads of headache. BTW comments are editable (within 5 minutes) and delete-able (any time)

Comment: Ok, thanks again. Sorry for the mess with the comments. I kinda panicked there for a moment. An instant later i saw that some kind person created this: http://bit.ly/lPta2Z. Again, I'm sorry, I'm under a lot of stress right now. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I saw that but I didn't think it had the DB Forge integrated. If you're in a rush, most of this stuff is simple to do with plain old SQL + php.

Comment: There's a DB Forge Factory in the code, but it isn't documented. I guess it works the same way as the Active Record Factory.